# passing array structure as pointer in function and initialize

Tags: c, function, structure, pass-by-reference

I have a problem regarding initializing an structure array to function by passing it as a pointer. I tried to multiply the counter from the size of my struct to track the array struct address in my next initialization but it gives me wrong output. Can anyone help me ?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma pack(1)

struct student {
    int idnum;
    char name[20];
};

void createStudent(struct student *);

int counter=0;

int main() {

    struct student s[2];
    int choice = 0;

    do {
        printf("\nMENU\n");
        printf("1.] Create student\n");
        printf("2.] Display student\n");
        printf("Enter choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice){
            case 1: createStudent(s);
                    break;
            case 2: displayStudent(s);
                    break;
        }
    }while(choice !=3);
    return 0;
}

void createStudent(struct student *ptr) {
    if(counter > 1) {
        printf("Array Exceed");
    }else {
        *(ptr + counter*sizeof(struct student));
        printf("The counter: %p\n",*(ptr + counter*sizeof(struct student)));

        printf("Enter ID NUM:");
        scanf("%d",&ptr->idnum);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nEnter NAME:");
        scanf("%s",ptr->name);
        counter++;
    }


}

void displayStudent(struct student *ptr) {
    for(int i=0;i<counter;i++) {
        printf("\nStudent ID NUM: %d\t Student Name: %s",ptr->idnum,ptr->name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just `*(ptr+counter)` will point to the next element in the array of structures, no need to multiply by `sizeof(struct student)`. Also, why not pass the exact structure variable directly to the function?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj because this is for my school project. My teacher want's to demonstrate initializing the array of structure using pointer to access the structure array

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj i tried *(ptr+counter) but it gives me duplicate data?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj i think the problem is in my display ?

Comment: Your display prints the same `ptr` contents over and over again. That is, you forgot the actual pointer arithmetic part.

Comment: This - `fflush(stdin);` is not a valid operation.

Comment: @kaylum can you give me the exact display ? is it *ptr+1-> or *(ptr+1) ?

Comment: `ptr->idnum` -> `(ptr+i)->idnum`

Comment: @kaylum can you modify my whole code to work properly?

Comment: @kaylum *(ptr + counter*sizeof(struct student)); is this correct?

Comment: I can, but I won't. That's your job :-) I think we have given you enough. You should be able to work it out. You can do it!

Comment: @kaylum i tried putting (ptr+1)->idnum it gives me wrong output

Comment: That's because you haven't replaced all the wrong instances. Your create has the same problem in the `scanf` calls. Wherever you would normally do `ptr[i].X` to access the array element replace with `(ptr+i)->X`.

Comment: You cannot use `scanf()` properly without ***checking the return***. See [Commandment No. 6 for C Programmers](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes are required.
(1) You are never incrementing the pointer in `createStudent`. So replace the line `*(ptr + counter*sizeof(struct student));` with `ptr += counter`
As `ptr` is already a pointer of type `struct student`, incrementing it by 1 automatically moves to next record.

(2) In `displayStudent` too, you are never using the incrementing `i`. So, after `printf` statement, add `ptr++;` within the loop.